# How can I get bonus experience for a specific skill?

Tags: runescape

How am I able to get extra experience when training a certain skill? For example, are there any items to modify the amount of experience I get for a certain skill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE:** Since 8 October, items such as pendants and recharge gems no longer need to be equipped to give bonus experience. If you have a pendant (they were removed 31 October from the Squeal of Fortune), right click it and select "gain-xp". You will get bonus experience in that skill.

---

There are many items which do this, most which are skill-specific:

## Bonus experience items for all skills:

- Not necessarily an item, but the [Clan Avatar](https://runescape.wiki/w/Clan_avatar). Gives a 3% skill bonus if the clan avatar has a skill experience boost and is on the same world as you. Gives a 6% boost if you gain experience near the avatar.
- The [Wisdom](https://runescape.wiki/w/Wisdom) aura. Boost experience gain by 2.5% for 30 minutes.
- [Fallen stars](https://runescape.wiki/w/Fallen_star). Can be consumed to give bonus experience in a specific skill or any skill if it is prismatic.
- [Refer a Friend](https://runescape.wiki/w/Refer_A_Friend_Programme). If you refer anyone to the game, you get a 10% experience boost.

## Agility

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Penance horn](https://runescape.wiki/w/Penance_horn) (or master)
- [Silverhawk boots](https://runescape.wiki/w/Silverhawk_boots)

## Attack

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Sacred clay equipment](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_equipment)

## Constitution

- Other than falling stars, nothing.

## Construction

- [Construction outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Construction_outfit)
- [Sacred clay hammer](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_hammer)
- [Volatile clay hammer](https://runescape.wiki/w/Volatile_clay_hammer)
- [Sculpting chisel](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sculpting_chisel)
- [Portable sawmill](https://runescape.wiki/w/Portable_sawmill)

## Cooking

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- Bonus experience from the [Clan Quartermaster](https://runescape.wiki/w/Quartermaster_(Clan_Citadels)) after gathering a certain amount of resources
- [Dwarven army axe](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dwarven_army_axe)
- [Sous chef's outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sous_chef%27s_outfit)
- [Portable range](https://runescape.wiki/w/Portable_range)

## Crafting

- [Artisan's outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Artisan%27s_outfit)
- Bonus experience from the [Clan Quartermaster](https://runescape.wiki/w/Quartermaster_(Clan_Citadels)) after gathering a certain amount of resources
- [Dwarven army axe](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dwarven_army_axe), only for Soft Leather or Soft Clay
- [Sacred clay needle](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_needle)
- [Volatile clay needle](https://runescape.wiki/w/Volatile_clay_needle)
- [Portable crafter](https://runescape.wiki/w/Portable_crafter)

## Defence

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Sacred clay equipment](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_equipment)

## Divination

- [Diviner's outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Diviner%27s_outfit)

## Farming

- [Falador shield 2 or above](https://runescape.wiki/w/Falador_shield_2), only on the patches north of the cabbage field south of Falador.
- [Saradomin's blessing](https://runescape.wiki/w/Saradomin%27s_blessing), only in Herblore Habitat
- [Witchdoctor outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Witchdoctor_outfit), only 30 minutes every day however
- [Farmer's outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Farmer%27s_outfit)

## Firemaking

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Dwarven army axe](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dwarven_army_axe), only for Normal and Oak Logs
- [Flame gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Flame_gloves)
- [Penance horn](https://runescape.wiki/w/Penance_horn) (or master)
- [Ring of fire](https://runescape.wiki/w/Ring_of_fire)
- [Portable brazier](https://runescape.wiki/w/Portable_brazier)

## Fishing

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Fishing outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Fishing_outfit)
- [Sacred clay harpoon](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_harpoon)
- [Volatile clay harpoon](https://runescape.wiki/w/Volatile_clay_harpoon)
- [Shark gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Shark_gloves) (only while fishing sharks)
- [Swordfish gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Swordfish_gloves) (only while fishing swordfish)
- [Shark outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Shark_outfit_(disambiguation))

## Fletching

- [Dwarven army axe](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dwarven_army_axe), only for Bronze or Iron Arrows
- [Sacred clay knife](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_knife)
- [Volatile clay knife](https://runescape.wiki/w/Volatile_clay_fletching_knife)
- [Portable fletcher](https://runescape.wiki/w/Portable_fletcher)

## Herblore

- [Botanist's outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Botanist%27s_outfit)
- [Factory outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Factory_outfit) (only while making unfinished potions)
- [Guthix's gift](https://runescape.wiki/w/Guthix%27s_gift), only in Herblore Habitat
- [Witchdoctor outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Witchdoctor_outfit), only 30 minutes every day however.
- [Portable well](https://runescape.wiki/w/Portable_well)

## Hunter

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Dwarven army axe](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dwarven_army_axe), only for Polar Kebbits and Crimson Swifts
- [Enhanced yaktwee stick](https://runescape.wiki/w/Enhanced_yaktwee_stick)
- [Sacred clay butterfly net](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_butterfly_net)
- [Volatile clay butterfly net](https://runescape.wiki/w/Volatile_clay_butterfly_net)
- [Zamorak's favour](https://runescape.wiki/w/Zamorak%27s_favour), only in Herblore Habitat
- [Witchdoctor outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Witchdoctor_outfit), only 30 minutes every day however.

## Magic

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Sacred clay equipment](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_equipment)

## Mining

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Dwarven army axe](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dwarven_army_axe), only for Tin or Copper ores
- [Gofannon amulet](https://runescape.wiki/w/Gofannon_amulet)
- [Golden mining suit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Golden_mining_suit)
- [Golem outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Golem_outfit)
- Bonus experience from the [Clan Quartermaster](https://runescape.wiki/w/Quartermaster_(Clan_Citadels)) after gathering a certain amount of resources
- [Penance horn](https://runescape.wiki/w/Penance_horn) (or master)
- [Sacred clay pickaxe](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_pickaxe)
- [Volatile clay pickaxe](https://runescape.wiki/w/Volatile_clay_pickaxe)

## Prayer

- [First age equipment](https://runescape.wiki/w/First_age_equipment)
- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Corruption](https://runescape.wiki/w/Corruption), [Harmony](https://runescape.wiki/w/Harmony_(aura)) and [Salvation](https://runescape.wiki/w/Salvation)

## Ranged

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Sacred clay equipment](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_equipment)

## Runecrafting

- [Air rune crafting gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Air_runecrafting_gloves) (only while runecrafting air runes)
- [Earth rune crafting gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Earth_runecrafting_gloves) (only while runecrafting earth runes)
- [Water rune crafting gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Water_runecrafting_gloves) (only while runecrafting water runes)
- [Master runecrafter robes](https://runescape.wiki/w/Master_runecrafter_robes)
- [Ethereal outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Ethereal_outfit)

## Slayer

- [Dragon slayer gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dragon_slayer_gloves) (only while killing dragons)
- [Demon slayer equipment](https://runescape.wiki/w/Demon_slayer_equipment) (only against demon slayer assignments)

## Smithing

- [Blacksmith's outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Blacksmith%27s_outfit)
- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Gofannon amulet](https://runescape.wiki/w/Gofannon_amulet)
- [Goldsmith gauntlets](https://runescape.wiki/w/Goldsmith_gauntlets) (only while smelting gold bars. Superheat item works alongside)
- [Sacred clay hammer](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_hammer)
- [Volatile clay hammer](https://runescape.wiki/w/Volatile_clay_hammer)
- Bonus experience from the [Clan Quartermaster](https://runescape.wiki/w/Quartermaster_(Clan_Citadels)) after gathering a certain amount of resources.
- [Portable forge](https://runescape.wiki/w/Portable_forge)

## Strength

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Sacred clay equipment](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_equipment)

## Summoning

- Bonus experience from the [Clan Quartermaster](https://runescape.wiki/w/Quartermaster_(Clan_Citadels)) after gathering a certain amount of resources
- [Shaman's outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Shaman%27s_outfit)

## Thieving

- [Black ibis outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Black_Ibis_outfit)
- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Trahaearn exoskeleton set](https://runescape.wiki/w/Trahaearn_exoskeleton_set) (If you own any black ibis pieces)

## Woodcutting

- [Brawling gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Brawling_gloves)
- [Crystal saw](https://runescape.wiki/w/Crystal_saw) (only while training in the Sawmill)
- [Dwarven army axe](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dwarven_army_axe), only for Normal and Oak Logs
- [Lumberjack clothing](https://runescape.wiki/w/Lumberjack_clothing)
- [Sacred clay hatchet](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sacred_clay_hatchet)
- [Volatile clay hatchet](https://runescape.wiki/w/Volatile_clay_hatchet)
- Bonus experience from the [Clan Quartermaster](https://runescape.wiki/w/Quartermaster_(Clan_Citadels)) after gathering a certain amount of resources

Comment: Whoa, props for compiling such a complete list. One thing to mention, though, is that some of these items function differently than others. For example, some equipment gives a constant percentage boost while worn, some with set bonuses (i.e. lumberjack/artisan/etc. outfits). As of the most recent update, however, items like Citadel rings and skill pendants work differently: instead of requiring players to wear them to benefit from their XP-doubling charges, the bonus XP is transferred directly to the player to be gained over time, and the items become cosmetic or are destroyed altogether.

Comment: @WillR. Mhm, this is a recent update that should be mentioned. I'll edit my answer later:3

Comment: You should probably differentiate between an x% experience boost, like the outfit and x amount of bonus experience in the skill, like fallen stars, etc. Also, I don't think portable locations give extra xp.